# Is there any calendar view libs that support English as well as Hebrew(Arabic the same)

Tags: java, android, calendar

I found the most famous lib for calendar view

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

And really this lib works fine, but if I use it with Hebrew locale(rtl) so Calendar view change language and name of days, but direction of swiping and direction of days are still as English...

it should be vise versa.

Here my view in English

[image]

and here in Hebrew `android:supportsRtl="false"`

[image]

and here in Hebrew `android:supportsRtl="true"` (I don't know why, but except arrows direction nothing were changed

[image]

I found this fixing

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/pull/573

according to this fixing direction of days and mounts swiping should be changed... But in my case, no

What am I doing wrong?

Or maybe someone had this issue, how did you solve it?

Feel free to ask if I forgot about something

Comment: The major reason for downvoting is probably that your question is considered to be off topic for stackoverflow, as questions asking to find software are OT. The pull request you mentioned has not yet been integrated into the calenderview repository. Maybe you should comment the request and ask for integration?!

Comment: @dpr Sorry I did not get your idea exactly... If I understand correctly I have a question with a real problem for me I am asking for help me and instead of this getting down vote... Could you please explain one more what I need to do to avoid down vote?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it is explained what is on-topic. Some people are really nit-picking when it comes to this stuff and don't see a need to argue or explain their downvotes - I made this experience myself. Point 4 of the off-topic reasons mentions what is probably the problem with your question.

Comment: @dpr I get your idea, but anyway it is a issue that I don't know what to do...

Comment: Actually there is nothing much you can do with these kind of questions. Probably it has not yet been closed due to the bounty you awarded. As initially mentioned, your problem seems the be fixed with the pull request you already found. However the fix has not yet been integrated into the main branch of `material-calendarview`. You should comment on the request and ask for integration.

Comment: @dpr maybe you know is there any way to get that branch? Just to don't wait... Let's say kind of beta?

Comment: You could take the fork where the fix was developed (https://github.com/anasanasanas/material-calendarview) and use this for your app. The author seems to have added a release containing the fix (https://github.com/anasanasanas/material-calendarview/archive/1.4.4.zip).

Comment: Did you try the 1.4.4 release from the anasanasanas repopsitory? If it helped, I'll post as answer...

Comment: The fix hasn't been merged in yet, so assuming you're using gradle, you don't have the fixed code yet. Ask the maintainer to merge it in

Comment: @dpr eventually yes, it halped. you can post your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any other calenderview for android that would solve your problem. But I think you can stick to material-calendarview.

As you already mentioned there is a pull request that promises to fix the issue you're facing. This pull request however has not yet been merged into the main branch of the prolificinteractive/material-calendarview repository. That is, the changes are only available in the forked repository (anasanasanas/material-calendarview) until the pull request is merged.

The author of the fix for the RTL issue however provided a [release of the material-calendarview containing his fix](https://github.com/anasanasanas/material-calendarview/archive/1.4.4.zip). You can try to use this in your app to get like early access to the fix. The downside is, that other fixes that have been integrated into the original material-calendarview repository in the meantime, are not available in the forked repository. You can of course fork the repository yourself and merge with upstream master, but given, that the fix is from April this year, I doubt that it is worth the effort as there won't be that much important changes.

Additionally you should/could comment on the pull request and ask for integration. Probably someone simply forgot about it and will integrate in a timely fashion. The changes are not complex, have already been reviewed and the merge conflict is easy to solve. Thus I don't see why this fix should not make it's way into prolificinteractive/material-calendarview.

Answer (score 0):

The fix you found was not merged yet (you can see that it still have the label open).
It happened in May 17.
The latest version in Maven in since Feb 17 (1.4.3).

You can ask the repository owner to merge it for you and create a new version or to download the code and do the changes from the fix by yourself.